# How to disable SSL in Azure's DocumentDB?

Tags: mongodb, azure, ssl, azure-cosmosdb, blockchain

I'm trying to run a [blockchain explorer](https://github.com/iquidus/explorer) which requires connection to MongoDb. I decided to use DocumentDB, since it's supposed to be compatible with apps written for mongo. I used my DocumentDb credentials and found out that it won't work, because DocumentDB requires `/ssl=true` at the end of a connection string, enforcing SSL connection. This explorer cannot connect via SSL. So, I need to disable SSL for DocumentDB. How can I do that?

Comment: If you email askdocdb@microsoft.com, the DocumentDB team would be happy to discuss options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DocumentDB does not support disabling SSL (it's secure by default).

Answer (score 0):

As [blockchain explorer](https://github.com/iquidus/explorer) is written in nodejs, it should be pretty easy to modify it to connect using SSL.

Just append "/?ssl=true" at the end of connection string (i.e. dbString variable) generated .js files listed in 
https://github.com/iquidus/explorer/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dbsettings  (excluding  settings.js which holds the actual values)

Comment: Good info, but should be a comment, not an answer. The question is specifically about the ability to disable SSL with DocumentDB connections (which applies across a broad base of use cases).